# Vue.js: V-Model input is not updating when using JSvirtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am using JSkeyboard for one of my webpage and using the v-model to dynamically updating the text based on the input value. when I try with the physical keyboard all seems working fine. with the JS-on screen keyboard the value is not updating. The example code snippet below. the code snippet is just an example that I am trying to achieve. if the question answered somewhere else let me know I will remove it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { message: '' }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="input" v-model="message"/>
  
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('input').value+=this.innerHTML;document.getElementById('input').focus()">A</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('input').value+=this.innerHTML;document.getElementById('input').focus()">B</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('input').value+=this.innerHTML;document.getElementById('input').focus()">C</button>
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{ message }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the `value` property of the `<input>` element directly doesn't fire the `input` event which is needed for `v-model` to work.

Also there's no reason to be using `onclick` if you're using Vue, just use `@click` instead.

If `message` is the source of truth, then you should be modifying that instead:

```vue
<button @mousedown.prevent @click.prevent="message += 'A'">A</button>
```

This is overly simplistic but suffices for your example. There are better ways of implementing an onscreen keyboard but I won't go into detail about that.

`@mousedown.prevent` stops the browser from focusing the button when it is clicked.

Comment: It's worked, thanks for your help, Is there any resource i can refer for implementing onscreen keyboard in a proper way? i tried many js plugins, in the end, updating the value in the message is not working all the time.